# Rutas Relativas en SML

Tags: programación-funcional

Estoy intentando leer un archivo y agregarle unas lineas, pero solo puedo leerlo y escribir en el si ingreso toda la ruta desde el disco duro `( "C:/Usuarios/..." )` , cuando intento agregar la ruta relativa `("/archivo.txt")` no hace nada, ¿es necesario alguna estructura o formato especifico?

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, ¿funciona si usas `./archivo.txt` en lugar de `/archivo.txt`? Dependiendo del entorno que estés usando pueden no ser lo mismo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro estoy utilizando Notepad++, ya intenté cambiarlo por `./archivo.txt` y sigue igual, inclusive lo intente con el backslash.

Comment: No termina de quedarme claro. ¿Qué es exactamente lo que estás haciendo con notepad++? ¿Estás creando un programa que no puede abrir el fichero?

Comment: Es un programa que guarde la información de usuarios, recibiendo los datos mediante consola, estos datos tienen que ser escritos en un archivo .txt, separados por una coma, `val fd = TextIO.openAppend "C:\\Users\\Froilan Moya\\Downloads\\1.txt";` esta es la instrucción donde abro el archivo, el programa tiene ejecutarse correctamente independientemente de la pc donde se ejecute, por lo tanto toda la ruta que ingresé me lanzará darme errores en otras pc.

Comment: Entonces el problema no es con Notepad++ es con el programa que estás desarrollando en Notepad++, ¿no? Deberías añadir el código relevante del programa para que la gente pueda ayudarte.